# find $x$ and solve Equation $2^x + 3^x = 6^x + 6$

Tags: calculus

There is a Equation: $2^x + 3^x = 6^x + 6$. 
I tried to do a lot of thing but I couldn't solve this equation. 
one of the thing that I do:
I assume that
$t_1 = 2^x$ so $\log_2 t_1 = x$
$t_2 = 3^x$ so $\log_3 t_2 = x$
$t_3 = 6^x$ so $\log_6 t_3 = x$
so we have
$t_1 + t_2 = t_3 + 6$ and
$\log_2 t_1 = \log_3 t_2 = \log_6 t_3 = \log_6 t_1*t_2$
Then I try lots of way to solve my equation with this method but nothing happen!

Is it possible to help me to solve this? I'm sorry for bad English too.
Thanks.

Comment: this equation has no real roots

Comment: x is a real or an integer ? You should start by studying the function $f(x)=6^x-3^x -2^x-6$ and search for its zeros

Comment: Yes. why? I know that $6 + 6^x$ is even and $2^x + 3^x$ is odd so it doesn't have any answer in Integer but why about real number? How to prove that?

Answer (score 15):

Write the equation as $(2^x-1)(3^x-1) = -5$. If $x \geq 0$ then both factors on the left hand side are nonnegative, and if $x<0$ then both factors are negative. Either way, the product is nonnegative, hence it can't be $-5$.

Comment: I think that it has answer in real number but it doesn't have. Thanks for answer.